# Проблема с кодировкой (судя по всему) в VS Code

Tags: javascript, кодировка, visual-studio-code

При **Run Code** написанной функции в **VS Code** выдаёт иероглифы. 
При открытии файла с игрой написанной на JS - русские символы заменяет на иегроглифы. Пробовал выставлять uft-8, windows 1251, windows 1252. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Скрины проблемы]

Comment: сохраните файл как  Unicode

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а как это сделать ??

Comment: самое простое - откройте файл в Notepad и выберите Save As